# How do you loop through an array, perform calculations on the arrays and plot the results?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, plot

I am very new to programming, and would appreciate some assistance with my program.  I'm trying to read in arrays through a for loop, do some calculations on them and plot the result on a 3D graph, but it gives me the error:

```
IndexError: index 753 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 753
```

Here's the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from itertools import product, combinations
from numpy import *
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")

ra_day = loadtxt("RA Days.txt")  
ra_minute = loadtxt("RA Minutes.txt")
ra_second = loadtxt("RA Seconds.txt")
ra = ra_day + (ra_minute/60) + (ra_second/3600)  

dec_day = loadtxt("DEC Days.txt")  
dec_minute = loadtxt("DEC Minutes.txt")
dec_second = loadtxt("DEC Seconds.txt")
dec = dec_day + (dec_minute/60) + (dec_second/3600)  

dist = loadtxt("Distance.txt") 

for i in range(len(ra)):
    x = math.cos(ra[i]) * (dist[i] * math.cos(dec[i]))
    y = math.sin(ra[i]) * (dist[i] * math.cos(dec[i]))
    z = dist * math.sin(dec[i])

ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="b",s=100)
ax.scatter([x],[y],[z],color="k",s=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: presumably `ra` and `dec` are not the same length.

Comment: They are both of length 754.

Comment: Ok that's solved, but now it says "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" even thought when I print it ra, dec, and dist have the same length of 753

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language but generally an index out of bounds is when the starting and ending indexes are incorrect.  Starting at zero until length instead of length-1 etc.  Might be worth looking at that in particular until someone posts an answer who knows the language.  Hope I may have helped